# Internet Explorer 9 limit of number of processes

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, windows-7-x64

I am trying to run some tests with Internet Explorer. and I cannot run more than 58 iexplore.exe processes or 29 windows. I have Windows 7 and IE9.

Is there any way to run nore than 58 IE processes? Actually I need 100 processes.

I use this command line to run IE

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -noframemerging http://myurl
```

Answer (score -1):

Install IE11 - the latest version for Windows 7

Comment: It does not work. I tried with IE10 and IE11 and there is the same limitation.
Please do not answer just to answer something, if you do not know the answer.